# Modern and correct way to schedule notification in an Android application

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have implemented notifications in my Android application using [this guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification) and after some attempts, I got it working. Now, what I want to achieve is to schedule notifications every hour when the user has an active quest started. The notification will be there to update the user about their quest.

After some research, I found some old guides on how to schedule the notifications using AlarmManager. However, another post on SO and the Android forum said that using AlarmManager is bad practice.

Do any of you know how to properly schedule one or more notifications? Also, the ability to cancel the notifications when the quest is finished is necessary.

There is no backend involved in the app, so the notification should be scheduled on the device itself.

Kind regards.

Comment: Take a look at [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started) and [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started/define-work#schedule_periodic_work)

Answer (score 1):

AlarmManager works, but it's an older, less capable API.  It also doesn't save state around reboot.  Newer APIs include JobScheduler and WorkManager.  The first is used to be notified at a specific time and/or when conditions occur (such as gaining network connectivity).  It's meant for 1 time or repeated alarms.  WorkManager is for background work like a database sync that is low priority and meant to be done when the device has spare capacity.  Use whichever is appropriate for your usecase.  If you were just using an alarm, it's probably JobScheduler.

Comment: Will look in to this, do you happen to know a simple how to or tutorial on how to use the JobScheduler for notifications?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Hey, I have a notification issue would appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949162/scheduled-notification-not-appearing-andriod-13

Answer (score 1):

The modern way of scheduling jobs with notifications is [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), WorkManager is the recommended solution for persistent work, you don't need to use a service or any threading mechanism to get tasks done, Also you can use it just as a Notification scheduler as well.

WorkManager also uses AlaramManager behind the scenes, but it's a more useful and efficient way to handle jobs, threads, notifications, etc

Comment: WorkManager is more for when you have flexibility over when something runs.  If you want it to run at a specific time, it's more of a JobScheduler thing.